# OL 5: Smooth transitions when rapidly changing layers

Tags: openlayers, openlayers-5

I have some png's (transparent radar images) that I want to show as an imagelayer. Had no problem doing so........I loaded an image, than removed it, loaded a new one, removed it and so on.....
But by doing it this way the transitions are not smooth (more like flickering images) like I would have hoped. How can I make these smooth??

```
var center = ol.proj.transform([5.2, 52.443], 'EPSG:4326', 'EPSG:3857');

var map = new ol.Map({
        target: 'map',
        controls: ol.control.defaults({
            attributionOptions: /** @type {olx.control.AttributionOptions} */ ({
                collapsible: true
            })
        }),
        layers: [
            new ol.layer.Tile({
                source: new ol.source.OSM({
                    url: 'http://{a-c}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png'
                })
            })

        ],
        view: new ol.View({
            center: center,
            zoom: 6
        })
    });

var url = url of transparent radarimage (http://......)
var imageBounds = [0.813 , 50.520 , 10.996, 54.295 ];

var imageLayer = new ol.layer.Image({
    opacity: opacity,
    source: new ol.source.ImageStatic({
        url: url,
        imageSize: [1315, 799],
        projection: map.getView().getProjection(),
        imageExtent: ol.extent.applyTransform(imageBounds, ol.proj.getTransform("EPSG:4326", "EPSG:3857"))
    })
});

map.addLayer(imageLayer); // to add imageLayer to the map.

map.removeLayer(imageLayer); // to remove imageLayer from the map.
```

EDIT 2: tried, as suggested (thx!), to update the source using:

```
s = new ol.source.Image({
    source: new ol.source.ImageStatic({
        url: url
    })
});

l=map.getLayers().getArray()[1]; // 1 = Radar layer

l.setSource(s);
```

Layers are not being refreshed.......

Comment: You could try updating the existing layer using imageLayer.setSource() instead of removing and adding.

Comment: Thx!.......tried that, but the layer doesn't refresh??

I used this code to change the source.......see original question.....

Comment: Thx to Mike (he pointed me to setSource) I found the solution..........https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/245358/animate-layer-image-changing-source-staticimage